# Toggle an event on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I want to trigger an event when a user scroll down between 30 and 20pixels, then trigger the opposite action when they scroll back up:

```
var flagscroll=true;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();
  if( y < 30 && y > 20 && flagscroll==true ) {
        flagscroll=false;
       $('[data-label="SearchPanel"]').animate({ 
            top: "-=34px",
        }, 200 );
  }
});
// how do I do the opposite action?
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/), I think its what you're looking for. Below is the js you could use making sure to replace with the correct div according to your markup:

```
$(function () { 
     $('#div-it-needs-to-reach').waypoint(function (){ 
         alert("Waypoint reached."); 
     }) 
});
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. The link may become obsolete if the linked page changes.